# Avoiding Duplicate Entries in Concurrent POST API Calls When Updating Shared Resource

Tags: .net, angular, http, rxjs

I'm working on a web application where I encounter an issue with concurrent POST API calls leading to duplicate entries. The application processes entities that share a common identifier, and updates to this shared resource need to be coordinated to prevent duplication.

Here's the scenario:

- The process begins with importing data, which initializes an entity
  with a shared identifier missing in the import data.
- Moving forward in the application workflow triggers POST API calls to update details
  related to the shared identifier for each entity.
- Since there are multiple entities associated with the same identifier, this results
  in multiple POST calls happening in quick succession.
- To manage
  updates, a function is designed to recreate the shared resource for
  these entities.
- This includes a step where existing records tied to
  the entities are deleted before new ones are created to ensure
  there's no duplication.
- Despite the delete-before-create logic, the
  nearly simultaneous execution of these POST calls results in the
  second call not "seeing" the deletion made by the first, causing
  duplicate entries.

As a workaround, I implemented a timeout delay in
the frontend between these POST calls, which resolved the duplication
issue. However, I recognize this is not an ideal or reliable
solution, especially at scale.

How can I effectively manage these concurrent API calls to update a shared resource without running into race conditions or having to rely on frontend timeouts?

Are there established patterns or strategies within backend development to handle this scenario, perhaps involving queueing mechanisms or transaction locks that could be more effective?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you create a minimal repro on stackblitz that'd help

Comment: sounds like you should google something like "concurrency strategies optimistic pessimistic"  I use a rev# and compare current view with data.  That tells me if another user has updated the record, but not clear on what is meant by "Since there are multiple entities associated with the same identifier, this results in multiple POST calls happening in quick succession".  Maybe that's the issue right there?  Are there not UIDs for each record in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [distinctUntilChanged()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/distinctUntilChanged) if you can compare two values easily.

Use `debounceTime(1)` otherwise (it is better to check the form validity before `debounceTime()`).

For the request itself, you use something like:

```
action.pipe(
  switchMap(() => request())
)
```

You need to change it to:

```
action.pipe(
  exhaustMap(() => request())
)
```

For idempotent<sup>1</sup> requests (GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, and TRACE) you can use any flattening operator, for non-idempotent (POST, CONNECT) you should use `exhaustMap()` or `concatMap()`.

- switch - only run the last request, cancel the previous if still being run;
- merge - run requests in parallel;
- concat - run requests consequentially;
- exhaust - run the request and ignore any other requests until this one is running.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Idempotency](https://blog.dreamfactory.com/what-is-idempotency#http) is an important property of some HTTP methods, ensuring that executing the same request multiple times produces the same result as if it was performed only once.